# Just Audio not set the audio volume on Flutter (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, just-audio

I'm trying to adjust the volume of a sound playing with Just Audio on Flutter.
The setVolume function does not work (Android + IOS).
The sound is played with volume set on the smartphone.

How can I choose the volume for this sound?

Thre is my code :

```
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
await player.setVolume(0.5);
await player.setAsset("assets/sounds/sound.mp3");
player.play();
```

Comment: If even `player.setVolume(0.0)` has no effect for you, it is best to report the bug with the project.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I’m facing up the same problem! Did you figure it out? @GunnarEketrapp